# AspnetPublishHandler with name "FTP" was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have issue with FTP publish of ASP.NET 5, MVC 6 application to web hosting.
I set parameters for FTP connection (Validate Connection is OK).
My publish process ends with error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(386,5):
>
> Error : An error occurred during publish.
> AspnetPublishHandler with name "FTP" was not found"

I am using VS2015 SP1.

What is AspnetPublishHandler?

Where can I change/modify it? Its issue on my publish or it is issue of hosting provider?

Comment: As far as I know, ASP.NET Core does not support publishing via FTP yet. You will have to publish to the file system and then copy the files afterwards via ftp.